# Android ActionBarSherlock Fragment Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying some ActionBarSherlock Fragment Tabs. I'm currently having some problems in my codes. I'm using individual Tablisteners in my fragments. Please correct my codes if possible.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;




public class FragmentsTab1 extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener{
    private Fragment mFragment;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);

    }
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mFragment = new FragmentsTab1(); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from FragmentsTab1 to Fragment
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(mFragment);
    }
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Error Code : Type mismatch: cannot convert from FragmentsTab1 to Fragment

**Suggestion By Dixit Patel**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;




public class FragmentsTab1 extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener{
    private Fragment mFragment;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);

    }
    /**
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mFragment = new FragmentsTab1();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment);
        ft.attach(mFragment);
    }
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(mFragment);
    }
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    **/
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mFragment = new FragmentsTab1(); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from FragmentsTab1 to Fragment
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment); //The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment)
        ft.attach(mFragment); //The method attach(Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (Fragment)
    }
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.remove(mFragment); //The method remove(Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (Fragment)
    }
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab,
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: refer this http://www.mentby.com/Group/android-developers/fragment-problems-converting-an-app.html

Answer (score 0):

The error you get says it for you:

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from FragmentsTab1 to Fragment

FragmentsTab1 is not a `Fragment` - it is a `SherlockFragmentActivity` i.e. an `Activity`.

You need to rework your code so that you understand the difference between a `Fragment` and an `Activity`.

---

To further explain.

Your code says:

```
 mFragment = new FragmentsTab1();
```

But you have declared:

```
 public class FragmentsTab1 extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
```

ActionBar.TabListener

and

```
private Fragment mFragment;
```

I cannot tell what you are trying to do, but I can tell you that this is a relatively simple java error, which is why I suggest that you try to understand the difference between `Fragment` and `Activity`.

I can see that you are new to the language, so I suggest you read about how java inheritance and subclasses work - you will find plenty of resources on the web for learning java.

You will  see that you cannot "cast" one type to another if they are not inheriting from each other. "Casting" is what the error is about. Its like saying that a `Car` is the similar type of object to a `SoccerPlayer` - but they are not actually related.

---

That said, I really do suggest you use the sample code in ActionBarSherlock sdk, as it will provide you what you need. You will find it really useful to use as a starting point for your own app.

Comment: I reworked so many times. But I still couldn't get it. Could you please share a little knowledge?

Comment: I have not worked with Tab Fragments before, so can not give my personal code. There are great demo apps provided in the ABS SDK, and I use them whenever I have an ABS problem. So start with his working ABS Tab Fragment code, and use that instead of your code.

Comment: Regarding my codes. You are saying that I need to convert my FragmentsTab1 into Fragment? Should I just use SherlockFragment instead of SherlockFragmentActivity?

Answer (score 0):

The error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from FragmentsTab1 to Fragment" is because the SherlockFragmentActivity is an Activity, not a Fragment. If you want to create a Fragment you have to extend from SherlockFragment.

On the other hand Richard Le Mesurier is right, you have to understand the difference between Fragment and Activity.